# RxDart. Listener of BehaviorSubject does not get value after subject.add(value)

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have two classes: CurrencyRepo and CurrencyFetcher. From CurrencyFetcher I try to listen to the behaviorSubject that is in the repo. But when I add values in the behaviorSubject inside the repo, CurrencyFetcher does not get these values. What am I doing wrong?

```
class CurrencyFetcher implements CurrencyFetcherService {
  final CurrencyRepo _currencyRepo;
  StreamSubscription currencySubscription;

  CurrencyFetcher(this._currencyRepo, this._preferencesService) {
    _subscribeToCurrencies();
  }

  void _subscribeToCurrencies() {
    currencySubscription = _currencyRepo
        .getCurrenciesStream()
        .listen((currencies) => _handleApiCurrencies);
  }

  Future<void> _handleApiCurrencies(List<ApiCurrency> apiCurrencies) async {
  // implemetation
  }
}
```

```
class CurrencyRepo {
  final CurrencyApi _currencyApi;
  final BehaviorSubject<List<ApiCurrency>> _currencySubject = BehaviorSubject.seeded([]);

  Stream<List<ApiCurrency>> getCurrenciesStream() {
    _updateCurrencies();
    return _currencySubject.stream;
  }

  CurrencyRepo(this._currencyApi);

  void _updateCurrencies() {
    _currencyApi.getCurrencies().then((currencies) {
      _currencySubject.add(currencies);
    });
  }
}
```

I have checked that the values are added to the stream after the CurrencyFetcher starts to listen. And I have checked that in the moment, when I add new value to the stream, it has a listener. The first time using RxDart, may someone help? :)

Comment: I've tried to debug it, have put a breakpoint inside this callback and I've seen that the 'currencies' list is not empty, it has 61 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the function `_subscribeToCurrencies()` try to write

```dart
_currencyRepo.currenciesStream.listen((currencies) {
      _handleApiCurrencies(currencies);
});
```

instead of

```dart
_currencyRepo.currenciesStream.listen(_handleApiCurrencies);
```